# Search all worksheets

Tags: jquery

On Error Resume Next

```
If TextBox8.Value = "" Then ListBox1.Clear: Exit Sub

Dim X As Worksheet

Dim c As Range

Dim k As Integer

Dim m As Date

Dim n As Date

ListBox1.Clear

k = 0

m = CDate(TextBox9.Value)

n = CDate(TextBox10.Value)

For Each X In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

ss = X.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In X.Range("B2:B" & ss)

If (c.Value Like "*" & ComboBox1.Value & "*" Or c.Value Like "*" & ComboBox2.Value & "*") And (c.Offset(0, 2).Value >= m And c.Offset(0, 2).Value <= n) Then

ListBox1.AddItem

ListBox1.List(k, 0) = X.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value

ListBox1.List(k, 1) = CDate(X.Cells(c.Row, 2).Value)

ListBox1.List(k, 2) = X.Cells(c.Row, 3).Value

ListBox1.List(k, 3) = X.Cells(c.Row, 4).Value

ListBox1.List(k, 4) = X.Cells(c.Row, 5).Value

ListBox1.List(k, 5) = X.Cells(c.Row, 6).Value

ListBox1.List(k, 6) = X.Cells(c.Row, 7).Value

ListBox1.List(k, 7) = X.Cells(c.Row, 8).Value

ListBox1.List(k, 8) = X.Cells(c.Row, 9).Value

ListBox1.List(k, 9) = X.Cells(c.Row, 10).Value

k = k + 1

End If

Next c

Next X
```

Good evening

I'm working on a user model.  It is a research process that depends on several criteria.  There are two textboxes (date) and two listboxes (customer - product code), but this depends on finding multiple worksheets and retrieving them from the listbox.  Is there a search code like this?

Please display all checks in the yellow columns of the listbox based on the combobox and textbox options (Date)

Comment: What does this have to do with JQuery? Looks like VB?